# sharepoint custom list

Tags: sharepoint

How do I export custom list into different server on the internet(Development site to Live Site).

Any advice or direction!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a list template based on the list using *Save list as template* option of the List's settings page. Select the *Include content* check box.
2. In the Site Collection *Settings* section, click Manage list template gallery. Download the template.
3. Upload the template to a new Site collection's list template gallery using the same menu as in s.2
4. Create a new list based on the template.

Comment: I have taken back and restored the same site in a blank site. So every thing came up. thank you